# A paragraph from Chapter 1 of Proofs from THE BOOK

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, logarithms

[image]

The above is from Chapter 1 of [Proofs from THE BOOK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK), where $\mathbb{P}_S$ is the set of primes that divides some member of $S$.

My main question is the statement "$S$ grows roughly like $2^{2^{f(n)}}$ with $\frac{f(n)}{\log_2 n}\approx \frac{1}{k}$."

1. What is an expression of $f(n)$ here?
2. Does "$S$ grows roughly like $2^{2^{f(n)}}$" mean there exist positive numbers $c$ and $C$ such that $ca_n\leqq 2^{2^{f(n)}}\leqq Ca_n$ for all positive integer $n$, where $a_n$ is the $n$th term of $S$? If yes, how to prove this?
3. What does "$\approx$" mean in $\frac{f(n)}{\log_2 n}\approx \frac{1}{k}$?

Comment: It looks like in the 2018 edition of Proofs from The Book, this "proof" was expanded with much more detail, and the vague statements that are causing you confusion were clarified into more precise statements with neat justifications, in case you have access to it

Comment: @AlexOrtiz, are you sure? The paragraph in the question was from the 2018 edition.